# Heroku deployment of Gradle application: pom.xml missing

Tags: gradle, heroku, jhipster

I have an existing Maven based application on Heroku that I want to replace with a JHipster generated, Gradle based one. The steps I took were:

1. Develop the new Gradle based application using JHipster
2. run `jhipster heroku`
3. `git merge heroku --strategy ours`
4. `git push heroku`

Most of the deployment succeeds (`Node.js app detected`, webpack logging), but then I get an error:

`Could not find a pom.xml file! Please check that it exists and is committed to Git.`

It is correct that there is no `pom.xml`, because now it is a Gradle application. But apparently, Heroku still expects a Maven based one. Where is this knowledge stored and how can I reset it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already found out. You have to run this command, to remove the Maven build pack:

`heroku buildpacks:clear`

Additionally, in my case I also had to set:

`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs`

Or Heroku didn't know whether to run as Gradle or NodeJS. The latter is needed for JHipster based applications.